# Mod_rewrite - show only get value

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, web

I want to show only GET value in the URL.

**URL:**

```
http://something.com/index.php?file=test.png
```

**Rewrite to:**

```
http://something.com/test.png
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Sorry, SO is _not_ a free code writing service. There are tons of examples and tutorials out for you. Look at them, understand how things work, start yourself. Then, if you have a _specific_ issue, _then_ is the time to ask here and provide the code you have so far for us to help with. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following .htaccess will do your requirement mate

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?film=$1 [L]
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but it doesn't help. It shows error message:

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @polikit that error means ur url doesnt contain index.php . that code was as per your question which has index.php. whether the url u enters really contains index.php?

Comment: 'RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?film=$1 [L]'

Comment: @polikit updated in my answer too mate as you said so others would get benefited . kindly mark as working answer as others will get benefited